# How do I use ASP.NET MVC Html.RouteLink in Visual Basic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, html-helper

I think in C# you can create in-line RouteValueDictionary instances like this:

```
<%=Html.RouteLink(Model.Name, "SomeRoute", new { id = Model.Id }) %>
```

What's the equivalent in Visual Basic?

This works, but is quite wordy:

```
<%
    Dim d As New RouteValueDictionary()
    d.Add("id", Model.Id)
%>

<%=Html.RouteLink(Model.Name, "SomeRoute", d)%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%=Html.RouteLink(Model.Name, "SomeRoute", New With {.id = Model.Id})%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, you're not actually creating an inline RouteValueDictionary with this syntax.  You're creating a new anonymous type, and using the `RouteLink(linkText As String, routeName As String, routeValues As Object)` overload.  This overload uses reflection (I assume) internally to add the properties of your anonymous object and their values to a RouteValueDictionary to create the link.